# Can に mean the same thing as から?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-から

> あの野郎、どんだけジークさん**に**恩を受けたと思っていやがるんだ！

In this sentence, does に mean the same thing as から ?

Thank you very much for help!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a sense, yes, but に is the correct choice here. 受ける takes two objects, a "direct" and an "indirect" object.

- を marks the direct object, i.e. *what* is being received
- に marks the indirect object, i.e. *from whom* the direct object is being received

を will not be translated at all, and に will be translated as "from". から, too, often means "from" but applies more generally to verbs, even if they don't want to take an indirect object.

For 聞く, から and に have a different use:

> お兄ちゃんから聞いた。
> I heard it from my brother.
>
> お兄ちゃんに聞いた。
> I asked my brother. / I heard it from by brother.

In your case に受けた and から受けた mean the same thing, but 受けた wants its indirect object to be marked by に, so you should use に.

EDIT: As per the exchange with Chocolate below, I am not 100% clear on the difference between verb+から and verb+に any longer. It seems to be clear, though, that in this case both versions mean the same thing and both versions are equally acceptable. I also think a verb cannot take both から *and* に, so the difference in usage is even harder to determine (if there is any difference). I think that the example に聞く vs. から聞く suggests there is at least a conceptual difference, though.

Comment: お兄ちゃんに聞いた can also mean "I heard it from my brother". And.. どんだけジークさんから恩を受けたと思ってやがるんだ sounds alright to me.

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the comment. からもらう etc. also sound fine, but I think that I hear に more often. I guess that から is a more explicit way to say "from". Do you think it's wrong to say that に sounds slightly more natural in this context?

Comment: 何人かの人に聞いたんですが、「～から受けた恩」や「～から恩を受ける」が文法的には正しいと感じるそうです。私は、正しい文法では「から」だと思うんですが、日頃話すとき‌​は「～に受けた恩」「～に恩を受ける」って言ってるような気がします。（すみません、答えになってないかもしれません。）

Comment: 知恵袋で聞いてみたところ、「から」の方が良いという人と、「どちらも自然」という人に分かれました→　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13103662183（ベストアンサーは投票で決まったので気にしないでください。）
それから、Lang-8でも聞いてみたところ→ http://lang-8.com/425018/journals/283325009427821911604365279634949906020/%25E3%2580%258C%25EF%25BD%259E%25E3%2581%25AB%25E5%258F%2597%25E3%2581%2591%25E3%2582%258B%25E3%2580%258Dor%25E3%2580%258C%25EF%25BD%259E%25E3%2581%258B%25E3%2582%2589%25E5%258F%2597%25E3%2581%2591%25E3%2582%258B%25E3%2580%258D%25EF%25BC%259F また意見が分かれて、「から」がいいと思う人と「に」がいいと思う人に分かれました。「恩を受ける」について聞いたんですが、他の場合について言及してくれてる人もいました。(今更って感じですが…遅くなってスイマセン。。)